# Selecting the data from a table by grouping one column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table **T1** as shown below

```
ID PASSED   FAILED  PASSED_PERCENTAGE   FAILED_PERCENTAGE
-- ------   ------  -----------------   -----------------
1  380      172     50                  23
```

I need a SQL query which gives me the output as below

```
DESC           ID        TOTAL         PERCENTAGE
----           --        -----         ----------
PASSED         1         380           50
FAILED         1         172           23
```

**Note:** Table **T1** will always have only one row and the column **ID** will have constant value always as **'1'**
Could anyone please help me with this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `union all`

```
select 'Passed' as 'desc', id, PASSED as total,PASSED_PERCENTAGE as PERCENTAGE
from tablename
union all
select 'Falied', id, Failed,FAILED_PERCENTAGE
from tablename
```

Comment: You might need quotemarks wrapping `DESC` -> `"DESC"` without it you might get an error. Fiddle [with](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75235aec3ede6d249dc74112ef4d573c) and [without](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=96091da7e42e7ad1736dd9e48ba98f07)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12C supports lateral joins which is an improvement over subqueries (the table is only scanned once):

```
select x.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select 'Passed' as which, id, passed as total, passed_percentage as percentage
      from dual
      union all
      select 'Failed' as which, id, failed as total, failed_percentage as percentage
      from dual
     ) x;
```

Of course, for this sample data sample, scanning is not a performance issue -- unless the table is really a view that is quite complicated.

However, lateral joins are very powerful and worth learning about.